# Amazon cognito Identity ID (sub) + S3 bucket name

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am currently working on a webApp to let authenticated users (by Cognito User Pool) to handle their own s3 bucket. In this way, I would like to use the following variable ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub} in order to dynamically name my s3 buckets. 
This is what I am expecting about my s3 role linked to my authenticated users from my Cognito federated identities :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The value of ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub} looks like "eu-west-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx", but I know S3 name cannot contain ":" special character...

Is there any workaround in order to dynamically name my s3 buckets based on each cognito Identity ID ?

Looking forward any tips/advices :)

Comment: Are you aware that you have limit for how many s3 buckets you can create in your account ?

Comment: Yes @RasikhMashhadi, I am aware about this limit of s3 buckets, but wanted to know if there was any solution for this. Thanks !

Comment: S3 prefixes can contain colons. Unfortunately, some services like Transcribe do not like S3 URIs with colons in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rasikh mentions in his comment, there are limits to the number of S3 buckets per account. 100 by default, although you can get that increased to a maximum of 1,000 by submitting a service limit request to AWS. However, the solution is not scalable to any number of users.

A more common pattern is to create just a single s3 bucket, and only give each authenticated user the permissions to access a certain prefix (path or folder) based on their cognito identity's `sub` property.

The following policy ([taken from Example 2 of the Access Policy Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html)) gives a cognito web identity `s3:ListBucket` permission, but only for their particular prefix, and the ability to get and put objects, but again only inside their prefix.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

It's worth noting that this will only work for authenticated users, as unauthenticated users will get a different cognito identity, as thus a different `sub`, each time.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @lemming ! Will follow that design, will be easier to manage only one s3 bucket than many more.